# Java REST service. Info is not saved to file and my code doesnt read the file

Tags: java, json, eclipse, rest

I am creating my first Rest service using JSON objects for the data 
transfer between user and server, with the help of the Gson library 2.5.
I am not using any frameworks like Jersey or anything like that. (That was my
project requirment). The java version i use is 1.6 (part of my requirment) 
jboss server and Eclipse as IDE.

At the moment i have 2 small functions from a simple HTML form. The first is 
suposed to requests the data from the JSON file and the second is suposed to 
add a new json information to the json document.

Problem is: When i try to acces the JSON file, a array its returned with the 
last submited Person. When i save a new Person information, that information is 
not saved in the personsJsonFile but someplace else [have no ideea where].
My json file is found in the Projects main folder.

Any help is deeply apreciated.

GetData class:

```
@Path("/data")
public class GetDataClass {
@GET
@Produces("text/plain")

    public ArrayList<PersonConstructor> displayJsonFile() throws IOException{

    ArrayList<PersonConstructor> newLib = new ArrayList<PersonConstructor>();
    File jsonFile = new File("personsJsonFile.json");
    Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(jsonFile);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    while(fileInput.hasNextLine()){
        String jsonLine = fileInput.nextLine();
        PersonConstructor singlePerson = gson.fromJson(jsonLine, PersonConstructor.class);
        newLib.add(singlePerson);
    }
    fileInput.close();
    return newLib;
}
}
```

AddData Class:

```
@Path("/add")
public class AddPersonsClass {
@POST
public String addPersons(
        @FormParam("idInput") int idInput,
        @FormParam("surnameInput") String surnameInput,
        @FormParam("nameInput") String nameInput            
        ) throws IOException
{
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        PersonConstructor newPerson = new PersonConstructor();
        newPerson.setPersonId(idInput);
        newPerson.setPersonNume(nameInput);
        newPerson.setPersonPrenume(surnameInput);

        File jsonFile = new File("personsJsonFile.json");
        FileWriter jsonWriter = new FileWriter(jsonFile);
        System.out.println(newPerson);
        String jsonLine = gson.toJson(newPerson);
        System.out.println(newPerson);
        jsonWriter.write(jsonLine+"\n");
        jsonWriter.close();
        return "Element: " + newPerson + "has been added";      
}
}
```

PersonConstructor Class:

```
public class PersonConstructor {

    private int personId;
    private String personNume;
    private String personPrenume;

    public PersonConstructor(int personId, String personNume,String personPrenume){
        this.personId = personId;
        this.personPrenume = personPrenume;
        this.personNume = personNume;
    }

    public PersonConstructor() {

    }
    public int getPersonId(){
        return personId;
    }
    public void setPersonId(int personId){
        this.personId = personId;
    }
    public String getPersonNume(){
        return personNume;
    }
    public void setPersonNume(String personNume){
        this.personNume = personNume;
    }
    public String getPersonPrenume(){
        return personPrenume;
    }
    public void setPersonPrenume(String personPrenume){
        this.personPrenume = personPrenume;
    }   
    public String toString(){
        return String.format("\n%s %s %s\n", this.personId, this.personNume, this.personPrenume);
    }

}
```

Json file contains:

```
{"personId":5,"personNume":"Ursu","personPrenume":"Niculae"},
{"personId":6,"personNume":"Ivan","personPrenume":"Claudiu"},
{"personId":7,"personNume":"Hap","personPrenume":"Dorel"}
```

Comment: to test if you have path problem, use absolute path when creating or reading the file... e.g; File jsonFile = new File("/opt/dev/personsJsonFile.json")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to that you have not specified the path where to save the file.

Add the path when creating a file.

```
final String jsonDirectory  = "path to file";

File file = new File(jsonDirectory + "\\results.txt");
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It now saves to file but it deletes everything the file contains in order to add the new information. I will mark your answer as correct but if you can, please reply to why you think this happens.

Comment: Well its simple, you are writing to same file again and its overwritten instead of being appended with new data. If you want to append to existing json data preserving the format then your best and most reliable approach would be to not append to the file, but instead, read the entire JSON file and de-serialize to an object, append to the object collection and then serialize the output back to the JSON file. Btw I am not sure why you want to save the file locally as web service should return the response for each call and let caller handle it.

Comment: Thank you, i understand. I will get started on that right away. Unfortanely i am not sure what you mean by the last phrase. I am saving the data saving localy because i am not using a database at the moment and the theme of the project is client / server comunication. I am saving the data so i can perform other functions like edit / delete / get all data. Is there a better way to do this then saving data localy?